# Why is this integral Inequality true?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

I am reading the book "Introductino to Calculus of Variations" by B.Dacorogna and I came across the following inequality which I do not understand

$$ \int_{\Omega}(1+ |u|^{p-1} + |\nabla u|^{p-1})^{\frac{p}{p-1}} dx \leq C(1+\| u\|^p_{W^{1,p}})$$ where $p>1$ and $C$ is some constant.

I can only guess that there must be an inequality $$(1+ |u|^{p-1} + |\nabla u|^{p-1})^{\frac{p}{p-1}} = (1^{p-1}+ |u|^{p-1} + |\nabla u|^{p-1})^{\frac{p}{p-1}} \leq C(1+ |u|^{p} + |\nabla u|^{p})$$, but I do not see why this inequality holds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{split}(1+ |u|^{p-1} + |\nabla u|^{p-1})^{\frac{p}{p-1}} &\le \left( 3\max\{ 1, |u|^{p-1} , |\nabla u|^{p-1} \}\right)^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\\
&= 3^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\max\{ 1, |u|^p , |\nabla u|^p\} \\
&\le 3^{\frac{p}{p-1}}(1 + |u|^p + |\nabla u|^p). 
\end{split}$$